Working with ERLANG on a windows machine with IPv6 only
I’m running erl.exe on a machine with IPv6 only and I get an error. I discovered it trying to run RabbitMQ on an IPv6 machine.
Here’s what I have done

Installed Windows 2019 VM with both IPv4 + IPv6
Installed erlang, e.g. version 27.1
I ran netsh Ipv4 interface uninstall to remove IPv4
I ran erl.exe and I get an error message

This is the error message
=ERROR MSG==== 18446744072343088544 ===
Failed create 'dummy' socket:
   eafnosupport (10047)
=ERROR MSG==== 18446744072343091104 ===
Failed initiating I/O backendErlang/OTP 26 [erts-14.2.3] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [ds:4:4:10] [async-threads:1] [jit:ns]

Eshell V14.2.3 (press Ctrl+G to abort, type help(). for help)

Now, when I run the rabbit I get some other error on top of that, but I suppose the erlang is where I should start.
I tried inserting some content in .inetrc
{inet6, true}.
{tcp, inet6_tcp}.
%% {inet_default_bind_address, {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}}.
%% {inet_default_connect_options, [inet6]}.

The two top line parse correctly, but I still get the error message. The two bottom lines wouldn’t parse correctly anyway.
I also tried erl.exe -proto_dist inet6_tcp and the error still persists.
I investigated the sources a bit and I see it's coming from the next line in esaio_init, which seems to rely on IPv4 interface
ctrl.dummy = sock_open(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
Any suggestions?
thanks in advance

"%% {inet_default_bind_address, {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}}" Do you need to put in the IPv6 addressing instead? Something like "%% {inet_default_bind_address, {::}}" or "__"%% {inet_default_bind_address, {0}}" or "%% {inet_default_bind_address, {0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0}}_"
